# How can i copy and move all Folder which are older than 30 days to a _History folder?

Tags: python, copy, move

Structure: **20170410.1207.te** <- Date (2017 04 10 , 12:07)

There is a company folder that contains several folders. All folders with the above structure which are  older than 30 days should be moved to the folder `_History` (basically archiving them), but at least 5 should be left no matter which timestamp.

As a time value, the string must be taken from the folder name to be converted as a date and compared to today's date minus 30 days.

I also want to create a log file that logs when which folders were moved at what location.

The Code below just shows me the filename, can somebody help me please?

```
import os
import shutil

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Python-Script\Spielwiese"):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(file))

shutil.move("C:\Python-Script\Spielwiese\", "C:\Python-Script\Spielwiese2")
```

Comment: So, first thing: How do you want to determine the age of the files? Windows' creation date? An answer on how to do this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: Yes with the Windows Creation Date.

Comment: @YungCarti Please comment in English only as this comment will only provide additional information/clarification for individuals able to read/understand German language..

Comment: @iLuvLogix

**20170410.1207.te**

There is a company folder that contains several folders.

All folders with the above structure should be moved to the folder _History, which are older than 30 days but at least 5 should be left no matter which timestamp.

As a time value, the string must be taken from the folder name to be converted as a date and compared to today's date - 30 days.

Also create a log file that writes what and where has been delete

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return a list of all files in a given timeframe, sorted by create time on windows. Depending on how you want to filter, I can give you more information. You can than work on the resulting list. One more thing is, that you should use `pathlib` for windows filepaths, to not run into problems with german paths and unicode escapes in your pathname.

```
import os
import shutil

found_files = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Python-Script\Spielwiese"):
    for file in files:
        name = os.path.join(file)
        create_date = os.path.getctime(file)
        if create_date > some_time: # Put the timeframe here
            found_files.append((name, create_date))
found_files.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1]) # Sort the files according to creation time
```

Comment: how do I specify the time frame?

Comment: you set some time, using e.g. `datetime.now()` or some other point in time using the `time` or `datetime` package.